# Python Simple Salesforce Select All Fields

Tags: python, salesforce, soql, simple-salesforce

I'm using Python Simple-Salesforce to query data via SOQL. I know that "SELECT *" is not supported in SOQL syntax, so I want to create a Python script to gather a string list of all fields to insert into the SELECT statement. Below is how I am describing the Account Object:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from simple_salesforce import SFType

#(credentials hidden)
sf = Salesforce(username=username, password=password,
                security_token=security_token, sandbox=True, 
                client_id='mwheeler App')

desc = sf.Account.describe()  
print(desc)
```

How should I extract the field names into a string list from the Ordered Dictionary shown below?

**desc**:

OrderedDict([('actionOverrides', []), ('activateable', False), ('childRelationships', [OrderedDict([('cascadeDelete', False), ('childSObject', 'Account'), ('deprecatedAndHidden', False), ('field', 'ParentId'), ('junctionIdListNames', []), ('junctionReferenceTo', []), ('relationshipName', 'ChildAccounts'), ('restrictedDelete', False)]), OrderedDict([('cascadeDelete', True), ('childSObject', 'AccountCleanInfo'), ('deprecatedAndHidden', False), ('field', 'AccountId'), ......

I will be using the string list to select all fields:

```
query = sf.query_all("SELECT string_list FROM Account")
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> How should I extract the field names into a string list from the Ordered Dictionary shown below?

I've extended your code to include the solution

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

#(credentials hidden)
sf = Salesforce(username=username, password=password,
                security_token=security_token, sandbox=True, 
                client_id='mwheeler App')

desc = sf.Account.describe()  

# Below is what you need
field_names = [field['name'] for field in desc['fields']]
soql = "SELECT {} FROM Account".format(','.join(field_names))
results = sf.query_all(soql)

# Alternative method to retrieve results
# I don't have any recommendation which to use
results = sf.bulk.Account.query(soql)
```

I realize the question was posted a while ago, just want it to have a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

This python library describe call can be seen here:

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/d2ba65e977730ce987ca7d3c38e0f8965d99eec1/simple_salesforce/api.py#L184

If I was you I would track back on how they got the Ordered Dictionary in the first place.

You can see from this line:

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/d2ba65e977730ce987ca7d3c38e0f8965d99eec1/simple_salesforce/api.py#L187

That they use the Base URL from here:

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/d2ba65e977730ce987ca7d3c38e0f8965d99eec1/simple_salesforce/api.py#L173

Having that you can make the same call in your Workbench:

https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

With a simple google search you can then find some useful examples on how to traverse the dictionary, here are a few:

[How to do this - python dictionary traverse and search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380734/how-to-do-this-python-dictionary-traverse-and-search)

[Loop through all nested dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values)

[Walking/iterating over a nested dictionary of arbitrary depth (the dictionary represents a directory tree)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738402/walking-iterating-over-a-nested-dictionary-of-arbitrary-depth-the-dictionary-re)

As long as you know what you are looking for traversing a dictionary should be rather easy.

Word of warning, from my experience querying all the fields is great for Enterprise frameworks like [FFLib](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common), however some objects are not designed to have all fields in one SOQL Query.

Refer to this page for SOQL limits:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_limits.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
# provide credential information for Salesforce Session Object
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
security_token = 'security_token'
domain = 'login'

# Create salesforce session
sf = Salesforce(username=username,
                password=password,
                security_token=security_token,
                domain=domain)

# Get list of fields for TABLE
fields = [field.get('name') for field in getattr(sf, TABLE).describe().get('fields')]

# Concat fields ready for inclusion in query string
fields = ',\n'.join(fields)

# Convert into SOQL query
soql = f"SELECT \n{fields} \nFROM {TABLE}"
```