# Nested data-structure efficient looping

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am having the following data structure (and more other data with more level). I want to loop through it

```py
data = [ 
    {'region': 'EU',
     'users' : [
         { 'id': 1, 'name': 'xyz'},
         { 'id': 2, 'name': 'foo'} 
    ]},
    {'region': 'NA',
     'users' : [
         { 'id': 1, 'name': 'bar'},
         { 'id': 2, 'name': 'foo'},
         { 'id': 3, 'name': 'foo'} 
    ]},
]
```

Is there a nicer way than nested for loops?

```py
for region in data:
    for user in region['users']:
        print(f'Region {region["region"] User id {user["id"]')
```

I had a look through itertools, but could not find something that matches

Comment: How would you expect the hypothetical tool to know which keys to iterate through?

Comment: Efficiency aside, you might check out [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/) as it will allow you to query directly into the nested level.

Comment: With only two levels deep, there is nothing wrong with a nested `for` loop (which is also the case in the linked duplicate question). However, for more complex data structures the question still has merit IMHO, thus voted to re-open.

Comment: In another section I have the same but with 3 levels

Comment: I think this should be closed as a duplicate, but I think this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738402/walking-iterating-over-a-nested-dictionary-of-arbitrary-depth-the-dictionary-re is closer than the listed duplicate in the closed message

Answer (score -1):

"Nice" can be subjective and the double `for` loop you wrote is just fine.

However, if it really bothers you for some reason and/or your actual data structure is more complex, and you don't want to repeatedly write complex-ish traversal logic over it, you can **abstract away iteration details** into a custom iterator class.

An example, which you can generalize/adjust according to your specific needs:

```py
data = [...]

class NestIterator:
    def __init__(self, data, *keys):
        self._data = data
        self._keys = keys

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._traverse()
    
    def _traverse(self):
        for item1 in self._data:
            for item2 in item1[self._keys[1]]:
                yield (item1[self._keys[0]], item2[self._keys[2]])


for item in NestIterator(data, 'region', 'users', 'id'):
    print(item)


for item in NestIterator(data, 'region', 'users', 'name'):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
('EU', 1)
('EU', 2)
('NA', 1)
('NA', 2)
('NA', 3)
('EU', 'xyz')
('EU', 'foo')
('NA', 'bar')
('NA', 'foo')
('NA', 'foo')
```

The key thing here is that we didn't need to repeat a possibly complex/verbose iteration logic, all we did is changed one of the arguments to `NestIterator`.

Depending on the definition of "nicer", this might be the thing that you are looking for.

(but again, if it's just about two `for` loops, it's probably an overkill and I personally wouldn't bother)

Comment: NOTE: Strictly speaking, `NestIterator` is not an iterator, because it lacks a `__next__()` method, but the point was to show how to abstract away iteration details. Readers are free to expand on the idea, if they desire. :)

Comment: Why would you suggest a class with three methods to build a simple iterable with arguments - i.e. exactly what a generator function provides out of the box?

Comment: Fair point. Class is generally more powerful, e.g. if we need to track extra state that we want to expose to the user. But since we don't need this here, a parametrized generator function would indeed be more simple.
(and stressing again, assuming that we have a very good reason not to simply use nested loops)